# link facebook sdk selectively for ios version >= 7

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, ios6

How can I link an external framework selectively on ios ?
Facebook framework works for ios >= 7 and I also want to support ios 6.

Just doing weak linking doesn't work as its an external framework.

I am using fbcorekit framework

Comment: If you need to ask, this is probably your first app. Are you sure you want to support iOS 6 ? It must represent less than 1% of all iOS devices by now... Nobody supports iOS 6 anymore.

Comment: I'd even consider only supporting iOS8 and up now.

Comment: sounds good! done thanks!